# vector addition,resultant vector direction

Tags: vectors

2 vectors, $V_1$ and $V_2$

$V_1$ is  $0^{\circ}$ with magnitude $2$

$V_2$ is  $180^{\circ}$ with magnitude $2$

Add these two vectors together, I thought the resultant vector would be $0^{\circ}$ with magnitude $0$. But the answer I got from vector addition calculator say that the result vector has a direction of  $90^{\circ}$

I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the link to the vector calculator
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vector-calculator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\mathbf 0$ vector has no defined direction. The very concept of direction breaks down when the magnitude is $0$. In a sense, it points in all directions at once, since shrinking the magnitude of a vector in any direction to $0$ yields it.

Calculators are not generally designed to handle this concept. So when you ask it give you a direction for the $\mathbf 0$ vector, a calculator will often, as here, produce an arbitrary value. It doesn't matter. If two vectors have magnitude $0$, then they are both the $\mathbf 0$ vector, no matter what their "direction" is.

Answer (score 0):

$0^0$ with magnitude 2 points to the east. It is the vector $[2,0]$.

$180^0$ with magnitude 2 points to the west. It is the vector $[-2,0]$.

Hence adding them up points north. It is the vector $[0,0]$, which also points south, east and west...